# Rails Brakeman warning: Dynamic Render Path false alarm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, brakeman

I'm just getting started with Rails, so I'm using [Brakeman](https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman) to learn about potential vulnerabilities in my newbie code. It's throwing a high-confidence "Dynamic Render Path" warning about the following code in my `show.js.erb` file:

```
$('#media-fragment').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(params[:partial])) %>');
```

I actually expected this was a problem, so no surprise there. So I changed it to the following:

```
  # controller:
  def show
    if legal_partial?
      @allowed_partial = params[:partial]
    else
      raise StandardError, "unexpected partial request: #{params[:partial]}"
    end
  end

  private

  def legal_partial?
    %w(screenshots video updates).include? params[:partial]
  end

  # ...
  # show.js.erb
  $('#media-fragment').html('<%= escape_javascript(render(@allowed_partial)) %>');
```

Although I believe the code is now safe, Brakeman is still unhappy with this. Is there a more idiomatic way to control rendering of a partial based on user input?

Answer (score 8):

**Update (2/5/2016):**

This has been fixed as of Brakeman 3.0.3.

If the `legal_partial?` method is inlined like this:

```
def show
  if %w(screenshots video updates).include? params[:partial]
    @allowed_partial = params[:partial]
  else
    raise StandardError, "unexpected partial request: #{params[:partial]}"
  end
end
```

Brakeman will be able to detect the guard condition and will no longer warn about the later `render` call.

---

**Original answer:**

Unfortunately, Brakeman does not know that `if legal_partial?` is a proper guard. All it knows is that `params[:partial]` is assigned to `@allowed_partial`, and that is then passed to `render`.

You may be able to tell that `@allowed_partial` will always be a safe value. At that point, you have to consider whether or not it makes sense to add complexity in order to make a tool happy.

Just as an example, you could do this:

```
def show
  render_allowed_partial params[:partial]
end

def render_allowed_partial name
  if %w(screenshots video updates).include? name
    @allowed_partial = name
  else
    raise StandardError, "unexpected partial request: #{params[:partial]}"
  end
end
```

It's basically the same thing, except now you are hiding the assignment of `@allowed_partial` from Brakeman.

(Warning: Not necessarily "best" way of doing this.)

Comment: I can't seem to get the guard condition to work for model attributes. I've got a method on my model: `def sanitized_partial_path; if ["foo", "bar"].include?(attribute); "path/to/#{attribute}"; end;` and it still gives the false positive.

Comment: @Nick Brakeman isn't going to look at the contents of `sanitized_partial_path` (although in the future Brakeman Pro will). The example in my answer works because of the assignment to an instance variable in the controller action which is used later in the view.

Answer (score 1):

Using **brakeman 4.2.0**

I had a similar issue trying to render a specific **hand-positioned-and-named template**. Every product of my app required that specific named template. The template name came from the controller params as `params[:a_particular_slug].underscore`.

I solved with something like this:

```
  def show
    if @products = Product.where(a_slug: params[:a_particular_slug])
      render template: lookup_context.find(params[:a_particular_slug].underscore, ["featured_products"])
    else
      render_404
    end
  end
```

Here I'm looking for a template. If you need to use a partial, be aware that `lookup_context.find` third params set to true allows to search for partials.

You can find more about `lookup_context.find` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths.html)

Hope this helps.